# How can a tree be encoded as input to a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, stanford-nlp, deep-learning

I have a tree, specifically a parse tree with tags at the nodes and strings/words at the leaves. I want to pass this tree as input into a neural network all the while preserving its structure.

Current approach
Assume we have some dictionary of words w1,w2.....wn
Encode the words that appear in the parse tree as n dimensional binary vectors with a 1 showing up in the ith spot whenever the word in the parse tree is wi

Now how about the tree structure? There are about 2^n  possible parent tags for n words that appear at the leaves So we cant set a max length of input words and then just brute force enumerate all trees.

Right now all i can think of is to approximate the tree by choosing the direct parent of a leaf. This can be represented by a binary vector as well with dimension equal to number of different types of tags - on the order of ~ 100 i suppose.
My input is then two dimensional. The first is just the vector representation of a word and the second is the vector representation of its parent tag

Except this will lose a lot of the structure in the sentence. Is there a standard/better way of solving this problem?

Comment: What is the goal of the Neural Network?  Are there any outputs that the NN is to generate?

Comment: it essentially generates a second language from the english input so the goal is to faithfully represent the parse tree in the input much as possible

Comment: also looks like i miscalculated the number of nodes is linear in the number of leaves so maybe that approach of setting a maximum tree word count can work though itd be horribly inefficient for small inputs

Comment: I don't know all the details of this solution so I won't answer, but it may help: you can encode k-ary trees in arrays, which means you can encode them as feature vectors too. The issue will be that a sentence doesn't in general have fixed length, so naively you'll have variable dimension FVs which doesn't work. Can you say something about what you're trying to solve and/or the net's output?

Answer (score 5):

You need a **recursive neural network**. Please see this repository for an example implementation: https://github.com/erickrf/treernn

The principle of a recursive (not recurrent) neural network is shown in this picture.

It learns representation of each leaf, and then goes up through the parents to finally construct the representation of the whole structure.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Encode tree structure: Think of Recurrent Neural Network, which you have one chain which can be construct by for loop. But here you have a tree. So you would need do some kind of loop with branch. Recursive function call might work with some Python overhead. 
   I suggest you build neural network with 'define by run' framework (like [Chainer](https://chainer.org/), [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/)) to reduce overhead. Because your tree may have to be rebuild different for each data sample, which require to rebuilding computation graph. 
   Read [Improved Semantic Representations From Tree-Structured Long Short-Term Memory Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00075), with original Torch7 implementation [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm) and [PyTorch implementation](https://github.com/ttpro1995/TreeLSTMSentiment), you may have some ideal.
2. For encoding a tag at node, I think an easiest way would be encoding them as you do with word. 
   For example, a node data is [word vector][tag vector]. If node is leaf, you have word, but may not have tag (you did not say that there is tag at leaf node), so leaf data representation is [word][zero vector] (or [word vector][tag vector]). The case inner node that does not have word=> [zero vector][tag vector]. Then, you have inner node and leaf with same vector dimension of data representation. You may treat them equally (or not :3)

Answer (score 2):

Encode each leaf node using (i) the sequence of nodes that connects it to the root node and (ii) the encoding of the leaf node that comes before it.

For (i), use a recurrent network whose input is tags. Feed this RNN the root tag, the second level tag, ..., and finally the parent tag (or their embeddings). Combine this with the leaf itself (the word or its embedding). Now, you have a feature that describes the leaf and its ancestors.

For (ii), also use a recurrent network! Simply start by computing the feature described above for the left most leaf and feed it to a second RNN. Keep doing this for each leaf moving from left to right. At each step, the second RNN will give you a vector that represents the current leaf with its ancestors, the leaves that come before it and their ancestors.

Optionally, do (ii) bi-directionally and you will get a leaf feature that incorporates the whole tree!